# zLib on iPhone, stop at first BLOCK

Tags: iphone, http, zlib

I am trying to call iPhone zLib to decompress the zlib stream from our HTTP based server, but the code always stop after finishing the first zlib block.

Obviously, iPhone SDK is using the standard open Zlib. My doubt is that the parameter for **inflateInit2** is not appropriate here.

I spent lots of time reading the zlib manual, but it isn't that helpful.

Here is the details, your help is appreciated.

(1) the HTTP request:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.98:82/WIC?query=getcontacts&PIN=12345678&compression=Y"];
```

(2) The data I get from server is something like this (if decompressed). The stream was compressed by C# zlib class **DeflateStream**:

```
$REC_TYPE=SYS
Status=OK
Message=OK
SetID=
IsLast=Y
StartIndex=0
LastIndex=6
EOR
```

......

```
$REC_TYPE=CONTACTSDISTLIST
ID=2
Name=CTU+L%2EA%2E
OnCallEnabled=Y
OnCallMinUsers=1
OnCallEditRight=
OnCallEditDLRight=D
Fields=
CL=
OnCallStatus=
EOR
```

(3) However, I will only get the first Block. The code for decompression on iPhone (copied from a code piece [from somewhere here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSDataCategory)) is as follow.
**The loop between Line 23~38 always break the second time execution.**

```
    + (NSData *) uncompress: (NSData*) data
    {
 1    if ([data length] == 0) return nil;
 2   NSInteger length = [data length];
 3    unsigned full_length = length;
 4    unsigned half_length =length/ 2;

 5    NSMutableData *decompressed = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: 5*full_length + half_length];
 6    BOOL done = NO;
 7    int status;

 8   z_stream strm;
 9    length=length-4;
 10    void* bytes= malloc(length);
 11    NSRange range;
 12    range.location=4;
 13   range.length=length;
 14    [data getBytes: bytes range: range];
 15    strm.next_in = bytes;
 16    strm.avail_in = length;
 17    strm.total_out = 0;
 18    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
 19   strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
 20    strm.data_type= Z_BINARY;
 21  // if (inflateInit(&strm) != Z_OK) return nil;

 22    if (inflateInit2(&strm, (-15)) != Z_OK) return nil; //It won't work if change -15 to positive numbers.
 23   while (!done)
 24    {
 25     // Make sure we have enough room and reset the lengths.
 26     if (strm.total_out >= [decompressed length])
 27      [decompressed increaseLengthBy: half_length];
 28     strm.next_out = [decompressed mutableBytes] + strm.total_out;
 29     strm.avail_out = [decompressed length] - strm.total_out;
 30     
 31     // Inflate another chunk.
 32     status = inflate (&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH); //Z_SYNC_FLUSH-->Z_BLOCK, won't work either 
 33     if (status == Z_STREAM_END){
 34      
 35      done = YES;
 36     }
 37     else if (status != Z_OK) break;
 38    }

 39    if (inflateEnd (&strm) != Z_OK) return nil;

 40    // Set real length.
 41    if (done)
 42    {
 43     [decompressed setLength: strm.total_out];
 44     return [NSData dataWithData: decompressed];
 45    }
 46    else return nil;
 47   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and sorted it out.  The code is slightly buggy as it breaks if Z_BUF_ERROR is returned, yet on reading the [zlib Documentation](http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html) it turns out that Z_BUF_ERROR should not be checked on inflation, as it can be thrown even if the resulting output is fine.

Changing the code thus worked:

```
// Inflate another chunk.
        status = inflate (&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
        if ( (status == Z_STREAM_END) || (status == Z_BUF_ERROR) )
            done = YES;
```

Hope this works for you.

EDIT:  (18th June 2011)
Here is the full inflation method, as requested.  It is implemented as a category on NSData:

```
@interface NSData (NSDataExtension)
- (NSData *) zlibInflate;
@end

@implementation NSData (NSDataExtension)
- (NSData *)zlibInflate
{
if ([self length] == 0) return self;

unsigned full_length = [self length];
unsigned half_length = [self length] / 2;

NSMutableData *decompressed = [NSMutableData dataWithLength: full_length + half_length];
BOOL done = NO;
int status;

z_stream strm;
strm.next_in = (Bytef *)[self bytes];
strm.avail_in = [self length];
strm.total_out = 0;
strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;

if (inflateInit (&strm) != Z_OK) return nil;

while (!done)
{
    // Make sure we have enough room and reset the lengths.
    if (strm.total_out >= [decompressed length])
        [decompressed increaseLengthBy: half_length];
    strm.next_out = [decompressed mutableBytes] + strm.total_out;
    strm.avail_out = [decompressed length] - strm.total_out;

    // Inflate another chunk.
    status = inflate (&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
    if (
        (status == Z_STREAM_END) || (status == Z_BUF_ERROR) 
        )
        done = YES;
    else if (status != Z_OK) break;
}
if (inflateEnd (&strm) != Z_OK) return nil;

// Set real length.
if (done)
{
    [decompressed setLength: strm.total_out];
    return [NSData dataWithData: decompressed];
}
else return nil;
}
@end
```

Carlos

Comment: Hi, Carlos,
It's very encouraging to see someone finally got it work.

However, I made the change you suggested, it doesn't work either. I am afraid my code has other problems.

So, can you attach the whole inflation code here?


Thanks!
Cedric

Comment: Hi Cedric, sure i'll try to remember to dig it out

Comment: As promised, I dug out the code; I'll try to post it as another answer.  If it helps you, maybe you could mark as correct.